# What would you call someone who imposes on other people's generosity?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What would you call someone who isn't afraid to ask for money or any kind of favor or who misinterprets someone's generosity for a consistent resource for what they need?

Comment: Start here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bum

Comment: It's worth noting the different usages of *bum* on the different sides of the Atlantic. For BrE, start with ***scrounger***.

Comment: 'kind of a jerk'?

Comment: It's interesting how many different words there are for this...

also @AndrewLeach I find 'bum' to be quite common in Britain (e.g. 'can I bum a cigarette off you?')

Answer (score 54):

A [freeloader](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freeloader)

> a person who habitually depends on the charity of others for food, shelter, etc.

[The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 42):

We used the term "[mooch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mooch?s=t)" (def 7) when I was younger. I think that one literary offering is "takers" (Ayn Rand's *Atlas Shrugged*)

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing a link to a definition of *mooch*. For example: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mooch And *moocher* is an alternative form of the word that is more recognizable as a noun.

Comment: I thought that the use of it as a noun was limited to my friends in high school so I didn't expect to find it in any dictionary.

Comment: Google it and you will find that it is, indeed, an entry in numerous dictionaries. Add a link and I'll give you an upvote and remove my comments.

Comment: leave the comments and don't worry about an upvote. You have validated my childhood vocabulary. That's worth more to me.

Comment: Please add moocher into your answer

Answer (score 35):

A [leech](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leech)

> 3
> : a hanger-on who seeks advantage or gain

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: I will agree with WayfaringStranger and say the term for that type of person is leech. If Leech Attached Then SoonDead = True End If

Comment: @ZafKhan Is that pseudo-VB?

Answer (score 25):

You could also call that person a [*sponge*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sponge):

> **sponge** *n.*
>   8. One who habitually depends on others for one's own maintenance.

The term *sponger* is also used to mean the same thing, chiefly in British English.

Comment: Yes for *sponger*, which in my experience is used quite naturally in the UK to mean *scrounger*. But if I ever see/hear *"He's a sponge"*, it's likely to be followed by further explanatory text (perhaps explicitly saying he sponges up other people's money, but perhaps he's a sponge for *information, praise, knowledge*, etc.).

Comment: I've heard it used in a positive way to describing a child's impressive learning abilities.

Comment: My memory is like a sponge... it's got lots of holes in it.

Comment: In Britain it is definitely **sponger**.

Answer (score 16):

One meaning of the word [parasite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parasite) is:

> One who habitually takes advantage of the generosity of others without making any useful return.

Answer (score 14):

Would you allow the Yiddish [schnorrer](http://wordsmith.org/words/schnorrer.html)?

> “One who habitually takes advantage of others' generosity, often
>   through an air of entitlement.”

Comment: Reb Levi Yitzchak of Berditchov actually was known to take (food, etc.) from others because otherwise the tzedakah funds would have gone to waste.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Do you have a source for that please?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Unfortunately I cannot remember 100%.  IIRC, however, it was in a book that is a compilation of stories that were told over by Rabbi Shlomoh Carlebach a"h. Levi Yitzchak Berditchover and also Reb Zusha of Anipoly.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok:  The 1928 Marx Brothers musical, Animal Crackers, featured a Bert Kalmer and Harry Ruby song introducing Groucho's character using the term: CHORUS: "Hooray for Captain Spalding, the African Explorer,"GROUCHO: "Did someone say a <i>schnorrer</i>?<br>CHORUS: "Hooray, hooray, hooray."  <p>Indeed, Groucho's Capt. Spalding was indeed a schnorrer, moocher, and fraud, and terrific.

Answer (score 13):

A [scrounger](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scrounger?q=scrounger):

> a person who borrows from or lives off others

Answer (score 7):

A *taker*. It's colloquial, but spot on.

Answer (score 6):

***"Opportunist":***

> One who takes advantage of any opportunity to achieve an end, often
>   with no regard for principles or consequences.

From the FreeDictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

[Exploitative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exploitative), as in 'tending to make use of selfishly or unethically'.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with Dan; I'd call that person a [***mooch***](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mooch). From NOAD:

> **mooch**
> (*verb*) ask for or obtain (something) without paying for it
> (*noun*) a beggar or scrounger

You can also use ***moocher*** in place of *mooch*. [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/moocher) defines *moocher* as "A person having a tendency to repeatedly ask help of others, especially if they are making little effort to help themselves."

In British English, you could also use [***cadge***](http://www.onelook.com/?w=mooch&ls=a)  or ***[cadger](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cadger)***.

Answer (score 0):

***User*** was the first that came to mind... That person is such a user. I've also heard ***cat***. ...Once you give, they keep on coming back.

Answer (score -1):

I call them Shameless.

They have no shame and will beg for scraps.