# Is there a word for people who revel in freebies?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

By which I mean, people who strategically position themselves so as to acquire money/service/free stuff at the expense of another? I don't mean *extortion* (that's too strong a word for what I need). Basically, someone who is a sucker for free/paid for things and capitalises on the opportunity. Is there a word for it?

Comment: I remember seeing "Freebee" used to describe users of a freebie site. I'm not sure if it has any broader usage though.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94724/what-would-you-call-someone-who-imposes-on-other-peoples-generosity

Comment: Looks like not just the OP but even seasoned answerers failed to check the existing post. I'd say this is a clear 'duplicate' of 94724 not 'related'.

Comment: OP may check out the cited post and clarify if it serves the purpose, and if not, why.

Comment: Yes, it's a definite duplicate- for some reason I didn't realise the existence of that thread. Apologies to everyone for the inconvenience

Comment: @janexlane: If you're happy to accept it's a duplicate I shouldn't really argue with you, so I've also closevoted this one. But I think the other one is more about people who *seek to profit from the generosity of other **individuals***. Your question title (but not the *text*) implies you're asking for a word for people who specialise in taking advantage of ***corporate*** "freebies". Many would say these are totally different concepts - one is selfish/unfair, the other is simply an extreme form of *thrift* (generally seen as a virtue).

Answer (score 4):

> Q: By which I mean, people strategically position themselves so as to acquire money/service/free stuff at the expense of another?

*Scrooge* would be a good term for this, after the protagonist Ebenezer Scrooge in Charles Dickens' *A Christmas Carol*, who was initially only interested in acquiring money at the expense of all those around him.

> Q: I don't mean extortion (that's too strong a word for what I need). Basically, someone who is a sucker for free/paid for things and capitalises on the opportunity. Is there a word for it?

You could call this kind of person a *freeloader* or *free rider*, which is someone who will happily take free things without perhaps paying their fair share. The Yiddish word *schnorrer* can also be used for a *sponger*.

All these terms carry somewhat negative overtones.

Comment: +1 for ***freeloader"***.  That's the word that always comes to my mind.

Comment: * that and "scrounger"

Comment: I understand Scrooge as a miser, but not a moocher. (The message of the story would be weaker if he were a parasite.)  His sin is valuing money too much and other things too little.