# Is there a word for people who revel in freebies that isn't pejorative?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, neologisms

I was looking for a word for someone that is really into getting free things, that doesn't necessarily carry a negative connotation.  I'd describe them as:

- that person that shows up to *random* meetings in college just for the free pizza.
- someone willing to send in postcard entries to a sweepstakes (instead of buying some product).
- a person that loves getting free stuff and constantly shares with others how they can get free stuff (i.e. the Points Guy).
- the child voted "mostly likely to get abducted by a stranger giving away free candy."
- a person that's overly excited about getting something for free.

If the word already exists (even if it isn't English), then I'd prefer that word.  I'm okay with slang/neologisms.  Thus far, the best I could come up with is "liberphile"/"liberophile".

Other similar questions that don't get to what I'm looking for because they're pejorative:
[Is there a word for people who revel in freebies?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95055/is-there-a-word-for-people-who-revel-in-freebies?newreg=3f07193e8cfe46af97781a250b100ead)

[What would you call someone who imposes on other people's generosity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94724/what-would-you-call-someone-who-imposes-on-other-peoples-generosity)

Comment: In New York City, we would have labeled it shrewd. But *imposes* in negative.

Comment: I think you're supposed to show at least one sample sentence with a blank where the word/phrase would go. / Frugal?  King/Queen of scavenging?  Scavenger extraordinaire?  Re-use maven?

Answer (score 2):

Some words I might use:

> Opportunity Hunter/Utilizer

> Cost Optimizer (Hey, this contains the sound "miser" !)

> Deal/Bargain Hunter/Utilizer

> Welfare/Gift Seeker