# I need a word for a person who excessively asks for favors without realizing/caring about much they are asking for?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

For example, the book "If you give a mouse a cookie, it will ask for milk."

Or another example would be a person who asks you to watch their cat for free and is thankless about it. Then, proceeds to ask a month later for you to watch their cat for a whole week for free.

Is there a word to describe this person? All I can think of is "favor-greedy".

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: I think this is pretty thoroughly covered by the [existing question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/94724/191178) (though all the words there can be used for people who aren't ignorant and rather know and don't care that they're taking advantage of someone).

Comment: *If you give a mouse a cookie, it will ask for milk* doesn't sound very "English" to me. What we say is [*If you give him an inch, he'll take a mile*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22give+him+an+inch%2C+he%27ll+take+a+mile%22) But that turn of phrase *isn't* mentioned anywhere on the linked "duplicate" page.

Comment: It is the name of a children's book, not an English proverb, and it is more like the [*Animal Farm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm) scenario.

Comment: "Entitled" is often used in such a context, even though it includes other behaviors/thoughts.

Comment: The background attitude could be called *presumptious*.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **bloodsucker** best describes it.

Like an insect or other animal that sucks blood.

You can see the usage here:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloodsucker

> Our landlord, the bloodsucker, just raised our rent again.

Another option could be **exploiter** - it's closer to the "favor-greedy" meaning.

Answer (score 0):

[Moocher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moocher) one who exploits the generosity of others : a person who mooches off others

[Parasite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parasite) someone or something that resembles a biological parasite in living off of, being dependent on, or exploiting another while giving little or nothing in return

[Deadbeat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deadbeat) one who persistently fails to pay personal debts or expenses

Bloodsucker and Exploiter have been mentioned by
@SeReGa

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above, moocher is the best

also about the saying mentioned above, "give him an inch...", I prefer, "you'll give him a hand, and he'll take your whole arm".

Comment: If you agree with another answer there's no need to post the same thing as an additional answer.